# display 2 two table records in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have tow MongoDB collection.
1) users
2) reviews.

at the first collection, I have stored username and id. and 2nd table I have stored user_id and comments and star rating.

I want to display on listing page users and his reviews.

I have written below code but it is not working.

```js
var getTopSellers = function () {
            var defer = Q.defer();
            User.find({ isRegistered: true }).sort({ updatedAt: -1 }).limit(10).exec(function (err, sellers) {
                if (!err) {     
                    if (sellers && sellers.length > 0) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < sellers.length; i++) {
                            var sellerDetails = {};
                            var tempObj = {};
                            try {                               
                                tempObj.reviews = getreviews(sellers[i]._id);
                                sellerArr.push(tempObj);
                            } catch (e) {
                                // console.log("catch error:-", e);
                            }
                        }
                        out = U.getJson(C.SUCCESS_CODE, C.SUCCESS, sellerArr);
                        defer.resolve(out);
                    } else {
                        out = U.getJson(C.KNOWN_ERROR_CODE, 'No data found');
                        defer.reject(out);
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log("Error:-", err);
                    out = U.getJson(C.ERROR_CODE, C.INETRNAL_SERVER_ERROR, b, err);
                    defer.reject(out);
                }
            })
            return defer.promise;
        };  
  
var getreviews = function (user_id) {
            var defer = Q.defer();
            Review.find({ user_type: user_id }).sort({ updatedAt: -1 }).limit(10).exec(function (err, reviews) {
                if (!err) {     
                    if (reviews && reviews.length > 0) {                        
                        out = U.getJson(C.SUCCESS_CODE, C.SUCCESS, reviews);
                        defer.resolve(out);
                    } else {
                        out = U.getJson(C.KNOWN_ERROR_CODE, 'No data found');
                        defer.reject(out);
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log("Error:-", err);
                    out = U.getJson(C.ERROR_CODE, C.INETRNAL_SERVER_ERROR, b, err);
                    defer.reject(out);
                }
            })
            return defer.promise;
};
```

Please suggest

Comment: Have you tried using aggregate function with $lookup pipeline?